# json request working in localhost but not in server

Tags: php, json

XAMPP 1.7.4 and if i run a php file with json encoded it works fine in localhost but if i migrate this to server the request receiving in the server is NULL, i don't know what is wrong and even for simple program its not working

This is my code

```
<?php header('Content-type:application/json; charset:utf-8');
if(isset($_GET['request']))
{

$str = $_GET['request'];
$arr=json_decode($str, true);


$username2 = $arr['username'];
echo json_encode($username2);
}
?>
```

This is my Request
**filename.php?request={username:kavi}**

If i run this in localhost my **output** is
kavi

If i run this in server my **output** is nothing

I checked by using **var_dump()** but its showing **NULL**

Can any one help me please....?

Comment: What does `var_dump(json_decode('{username:kavi}', TRUE));` output on your localhost? Pretty sure it's `NULL`.

Comment: Please show us the Javascript which is sending the request to the server.

Comment: Ya its showing NULL and if i use var_dump($arr) it showing output as array(1) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(4) "kavi"
}  in localhost not in server

Answer (score 3):

`{username:kavi}` is not JSON. Strings must be quoted with `"` characters. [Test](http://jsonlint.com/) your JSON (better yet: don't handcraft it in the first place).

Comment: Hi Quentin,i am new to development but i tried with quotes (filename.php?request={"username":"kavi"}) but still its not working if you don't mind can you please write a simple program so that i can check with my server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the true condition on
 `$arr=json_decode($str, true);`
I had the same issue, the json was working for me on WAMP but wasn't working when I migrated the code on the server,  having the following line of code :

```
echo json_encode($json,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I removed the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT and left just `echo json_encode($json);` and worked for me...